# Unicode accentuation on Lazarus with JSON

Tags: json, unicode, pascal, lazarus

I'm having a problem with accentuation on Lazarus, when I get some JSON some characters appears as "\u00ed" instead "í" for example. Someone has a solution?

The code is this one

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
S : String;
begin
  S := '';
  With TFPHttpClient.Create(Nil) do
    try
      S:=Get(Edit1.Text);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=Trim(S);
end;
```

Comment: Sounds normal. Use the fcl-json package to decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I made a class that convert unicode to UTF8

```
function TForm1.DecodeUnicodeEscapes(EscapedString: String): String;
var
  FoundPos: LongInt;
  HexCode: String;
  DecodedChars: String;
begin
  Result := EscapedString;
  FoundPos := Pos('\u', Result);
  while (FoundPos <> 0) and (FoundPos < Length(Result) - 4) do begin
    HexCode :=  Copy(Result, FoundPos + 2, 4);
    DecodedChars := WideChar(StrToInt('$' + HexCode));
    Result := AnsiReplaceStr(Result, '\u' + HexCode,
                             UTF8Encode(DecodedChars));
    FoundPos := Pos('\u', Result);
  end;
end;
```

and the previous code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   s: String;
begin
  s := '';
  With TFPHttpClient.Create(Nil) do
    try
      s :=Get(Edit1.Text);
      s := DecodeUnicodeEscapes(s);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=Trim(s);
end;
```